# Change browser scrollbar's scrollable height

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I'm trying to set the max scroll length for my site.

I'm preloading each main page into invisible div's, but on every page the scrollbar vertical height is as long as the longest page I preloaded form external html.

Is there any way to set the maximum scrollable distance with javascript?

I have these empty spaces now on each page...

Answer (score 2):

Change your `hiddenPageClass` to use `display:none;` instead of `visibility: hidden;`

Also, for future reference. Post relevant code here and/or an example at [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). Don't make us go to your personal site.

**EDIT**

You can see the difference in the two properties in this [About.com question](http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/blfaqhidden.htm).

Comment: much tnx. I figured the code would be irrelevant, but in this case it is.. tnx anyway

Comment: +1 Setting `visibility` to hidden hides the element but it still takes up space in the layout